# Changing character limit on inherited column of custom content type

Tags: development, content-type, site-column, inheritance

I've inherited the OOTB content type 'Announcement'.

I want to set a character limit on the 'Body' column for this particular child content type.

Is this possible/feasible or is this generally discouraged (in favour of just adding a new column)?

I'm asking because creating a new column, at this point, would have several potentially messy implications elsewhere in the site that I'd need to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a new content type (CT) but just adding the same Body Column to it?  That way you can treat it as a parent CT and not worry about the consequences of editing any of the OOB Columns for the Announcements CT.

Comment: I've considered creating a new CT yes but it seems like it's a rather elaborate solution for merely wanting to change one attribute of one column. Thanks. +1.